# when i get a new iphone, can i still test apps on my 3g?

Tags: iphone

i will be getting a iphone 4 but was wondering if i can still use my iphone 3g to test on?

Comment: Sure, just sign another contract with your phone company.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham No need for that. It'll still run apps and wifi without a valid contract (my friend gave his four year old his 3G when he got a 3GS, works just fine).

Comment: Why the off-topic close votes?  How to test an application on multiple devices is certainly programming related.

Comment: Assuming that the contract previously held means you can hang on to it without paying a fee to the phone company, which is not a given, either you have to have a valid SIM, in which case you still require a contract, or you don't have to have a valid SIM, in which case the poster should already have tried it without the SIM. Signing contracts and configuring items of consumer electronics are not programming issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless you're trying to test cellular data functionality specifically. It'll work on Wifi and/or without internet just fine even without a SIM card inserted.

Comment: +1 Yes. Also look at this knowledge base article that describes how  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3406